# What is a binary comparision and how is it different from a textual co

Tags: vb.net, vb6

If we are comparing two strings like "CAT" and "cat" and use vbBinaryCompare mode, MSDN says it does a binary comparision but what is a birary comparision? does it mean it does it in a case-Insensitive way?  How is it diffeent form Textual Comparision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vbTextCompare` is case-insensitive. "CAT" and "cat" are considered to be equal.

`vbBinaryCompare` is case-sensitive. "CAT" and "cat" are considered to be different.

Comment: It's not necessarily limited to just case sensitivity.  Binary compare is just that: binary values.  Text compare can be locale-specific and will treat equivalent characters for your locale as equal.

Comment: Dan is correct. E.g. on some locales I believe "ss" is considered equal to "ß". You might also find a sequence of combining characters (accents etc) would be considered equal to some equivalent character that contains the accent.